# Why is register array indexing undefined?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Looking at C11 6.3.2.1 paragraph 3:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of *type*" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to *type*" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has `register` storage class, the behavior is undefined.

*Undefined* behaviour seems like an odd choice for this situation. Undefined behaviour "imposes no requirements" (3.4.3). In other words, according to only the wording of 6.3.2.1, indexing into (or doing a few other things with) an array declared with `register` is presumably permitted to compile, run and do exactly what the code looks like it does without issuing an error.

```
register int a[5];
a[0] = 6; // apparently not required to cause an error?
```

This seems to contradict the spirit of the keyword, which (per 6.5.3.2) prevents an lvalue's address being taken with `&`. This is not quite the same thing, but it's certainly related, as implicit array->pointer conversion, and `&` on an lvalue, generate the same kind of result: a pointer to the object's storage.

The footnote to 6.7.1 makes this relationship explicit:

> the address of any part of an object declared with storage-class specifier `register` cannot be computed, either explicitly (by use of the unary `&` operator as discussed in 6.5.3.2) or implicitly (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in 6.3.2.1).

So if it "can't" be done, why is the conversion *un*defined instead of erroneous, or (for indexing, where there are a few other options) implementation-defined?

It doesn't read like an oversight in 6.3.2.1, since `register`'s meaning is straightforward enough according to the other mentions; I'd assume it to be perfectly well-defined if that sentence didn't say otherwise. What is there to be in doubt about?

Comment: Related to [Is it possible to keep an entire array in cpu register](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17342881/1708801), I saw that question recently although I can't remember why.

Comment: I wonder if the intention was to allow for extensions, but not impose any requirements on their exact meaning?  There are many situations where C suffers by not having a term whose meaning is less rigid than Implementation-defined (which requires implementations to specify something) or Unspecified (which requires selection from a fixed set of choices), but not so loose as Undefined (anything goes).  Personally, I think `register` could be a useful keyword if a function which took a parameter of type `register int*` promised not to persist the pointer, and thus callers of such a function...

Comment: ...could keep variables whose address was passed to that function (but not generally exposed) could keep those variables cached in registers while calling other functions (which might, *but for the register keyword*, be able to access pointers retained by the earlier function calls).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Undefined Behavior allows *everything*, including "behaving in a way that's expected on the particular platform". I.e. for a platform that has hardware array registers, you'd *want* it to compile, for a platform which does not you don't want it to compile. Leaving it UB allows both.

IIRC a 6502 had 256 memory-mapped registers at the start of address space.

Comment: Most 6502 instructions had an addressing mode which would assume the upper byte of the address was zero, so e.g. "lda 57" would only take two bytes rather than three.  Additionally, there were indirect addressing modes which would fetch two bytes from any two consecutive memory locations within the first 256 and use their values as the low and high bytes of an address.  While this meant that zero-page addresses could be used for purposes similar to the address registers on other machines, accesses to those addresses went to the external memory bus like any other.  The 6510 found in the...

Comment: ...Commodore 64 added an I/O port with a data-direction register at address $0000 and a data register at address $0001; I think the idea was to allow 64K of address space to be banked entirely as RAM, without needing to reserve a bank of addresses for the I/O devices controlling the memory mapping, but putting a general-purpose I/O port to the CPU seems a curious approach.