# Why can't access register array using loop

Tags: c, arrays, cpu-registers

I have Below Code

```
{
    register int a[10];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            a[i]=1;
        }
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            printf("%d\t",&a[i]);
        }
}
```

Error

```
rejarr.c: In function ‘main’:
    rejarr.c:6:3: error: address of register variable ‘a’ requested
       a[i]=1;
       ^
    rejarr.c:9:3: error: address of register variable ‘a’ requested
       printf("%d\t",&a[i]);                                            
       ^
```

But I mention the index position of the array that time I can the access the value of array.
What is the reason can't access the array using loop

Comment: You can get detailed explanation at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342881/is-it-possible-to-keep-an-entire-array-in-cpu-register and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-register-keyword/

Comment: You cannot use the adress of a register (`&a`), it doesn't make sense. I'd just drop the `register` keyword, it's doesn't make muchs sense nowadays.

Comment: Just drop the `register` - Let the compiler decide on the use of registers - it will do a better job that you.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you can't use `&` operator with a register variable. That's why compiler throwing an error.

[C standard 6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2432.pdf)  footnote 128 :

> 128)The implementation can treat any register declaration simply as an
>   auto declaration. **However, whether or not addressable storage is
>   actually used, the address of any part of an object declared with
>   storage-class specifier register cannot be computed, either explicitly
>   (by use of the unary & operator as discussed in 6.5.3.2) or implicitly
>   (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in 6.3.2.1)**.
>   Thus, the only operator that can be applied to an array declared with
>   storage-class specifier register is sizeof.

Answer (score 0):

For the second error: `printf("%d\t",&a[i]);` should actually be `printf("%d\t",a[i]);`. `&` means 'address of', but you want the value.
However, array indexing of a `register` variable won't work because...

---

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(keyword)):

> In C (but not C++ where the keyword is essentially ignored) **the location of a variable declared with register cannot be accessed**, but the sizeof operator can be applied. Aside from this limitation, register is essentially meaningless in modern compilers due to optimization which will place variables in a register if appropriate regardless of whether the hint is given.

So for the first error, you can't have code which uses pointer arithmetic, such as `*(a+i)=1;`, which is how `a[i]=1;` is probably implemented by the compiler. Unrolling the loops *seems* to work:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    register int a[10];

    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=1;
    a[2]=1;
    a[3]=1;
    a[4]=1;
    a[5]=1;
    a[6]=1;
    a[7]=1;
    a[8]=1;
    a[9]=1;

    printf("%d\t", a[0]);
    printf("%d\t", a[1]);
    printf("%d\t", a[2]);
    printf("%d\t", a[3]);
    printf("%d\t", a[4]);
    printf("%d\t", a[5]);
    printf("%d\t", a[6]);
    printf("%d\t", a[7]);
    printf("%d\t", a[8]);
    printf("%d\t", a[9]);

    printf("\n");
}
```

```
>gcc -S -std=c11 -Wall -c main.c && gcc main.o -o main.exe && main
1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
```

```
; ...
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, 24(%rbp)
    call    __main
    movl    $1, -48(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -44(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -40(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -36(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -28(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -24(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -20(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $1, -12(%rbp)
    movl    -48(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rcx
    call    printf
    movl    -44(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rcx
    call    printf
; ...
```

But notice that values are moved into the **address** contained in `RBP`!

---

The simplest solution (and probably best for readability, maintainability and compiler optimisations): remove the `register` keyword!

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        a[i]=1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

```
; ...
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, 24(%rbp)
    call    __main
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movl    $1, -48(%rbp,%rax,4)
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $9, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L4
.L5:
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movl    -48(%rbp,%rax,4), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rcx
    call    printf
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L4:
    cmpl    $9, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L5
; ...
```

```
>gcc -std=c11 -Wall -c main.c && gcc main.o -o main.exe && main
1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
```

Comment: This answer is discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391326/what-makes-this-a-bad-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`register` is an old keyword that requested the C implementation store the object in a processor register instead of memory. In modern C, it only requests that the implementation make access to the object fast, and it is nearly useless in the face of modern optimization.

However, some of the old semantics remain. Processor registers do not have memory addresses, so C has rules against using the address of a `register` object. When you use an array with a subscript, the array must be (automatically) converted to a pointer to its first element. That is, the address must be taken. This falls afoul of a rule in C 2018 6.3.2.1 3, which says:

> … If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.